# How to clear TPM 2.0 on Dell Inspiron 15 with recent BIOS?

Tags: bios, tpm

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 (7577), with BIOS version 1.8.0.

I wanted to issue Clear TPM command from Windows 10 (build 1903), but this appeared:

---

### Clear TPM - device does not support

[image: Clear TPM - device does not support]

---

In the UEFI, I haven't found any option named TPM, nor mentioning it in description.

---

So, how do I clear TPM on my current setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be very well hidden, on purpose..? Who knows...

---

Navigate in your UEFI BIOS to:

**Security -> PTT Security -> check Clear**.

Then a confirmation window appears:

[image: PTT Clear]